# How to set value on selected item list spinner on Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner

I have one xml file for title

salute.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="title">
    <item>MR</item>
    <item>MRS</item>
   </string-array>
</resources>
```

and after that i would like to set that if someone choose 'Mr', and the value that goes to application is 1(integer), and else its gonna be 2(integer).

I have tried with this code, but I have no clue about what I'm gonna do next.

```
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById((R.id.spinnerTitle));
    String spinVal = String.valueOf(spin.getSelectedItem());



    if (spinVal.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("MR")){
        textArea.setText("1");

       }
           else
        {
        (TextView.setText("2"))
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code by this

```
   final Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById((R.id.spinnerTitle));

 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.title, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin .setAdapter(adapter);

    spin.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
            if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("MR")){
                textArea.setText("1");
            }
            else
            {
                (TextView.setText("2"))
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: im confused about the structure since I am only doing copy and paste from website and mixed them up.

Answer (score 0):

add item selected listener to spinner.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and move your code in

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
 if (spinVal.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("MR")){
    textArea.setText("1");

   }
       else
    {
    (TextView.setText("2"))
    }
```

}